# How to use variable value in styled component that uses props?

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

I'm passing a prop named selected from my react component to styled component inside of which I want to do the following:

```
import styled from 'styled-components';
import {colors} from '../common/colors';

const StyledComponent = styled.div`
 background-color: ${props => props.selected ? '${colors.gray}' : ''}
`;

export {StyledComponent};
```

But the styled component isn't picking up the  ${colors.gray} as a variable and is still treating it as a regular string. Does anyone know how to achieve this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: `'${colors.gray}'` should be just `colors.gray`

Comment: You're already inside the template string interpolation there; you're writing plain JavaScript, just write `colors.grey`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Duh. It's really easy. I just had to drop the enclosing apostrophes and use it like
`background-color: ${props => props.selected ? colors.gray : ''}`.